# Android Sleeping Main Activity with a Webview using websockets

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, webview

I have an Android application that is basically a wrapper for a webview. The Android app is used to lock the screen on and pin the application, that all works fine.

The webpage that the webview loads uses websockets to receive live data which it uses to render data to graphical displays.

I'm getting a really big problem where after 10-15 minutes the graph updates slow down gradually to a point where they rarely update. I think its the main activity that is getting put to sleep by the OS. Once it has slowed down, If I touch the screen it will start processing data again but only while touching. It is still receiving the network data during this time.

I have the wakelock for the power and the Wifi, and have also white-listed the application to prevent any battery optimization.

Is there any way I can keep that main activity active while using a webview? Or is there some way to use a service that could keep that activity active?